# How to define var in shell script functions

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am currently using the below function

```
!/bin/bash

#Colour change functions

fnHotlinkG2R()
{
        sed -i 's/#hotlink {height: 200px;width: 200px;background: green;/#hotlink {height: 200px;width: 200px;background: red;/' /var/www/html/style.css
}
```

Rather than creating multiple difference functions I would like to enter the `#hotlink` as different every time I call the function from within the script.

I am fairly new to sh scripts and would like some assistance please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the first line should be hash bang `#!` then followed by the path to the program, not just `!`.

In bash, you don't declare parameter for the function. You just take the argument (and check whether it is valid/not empty) and use it. In this case, you may want to take the first argument from the function by `$1` and replace #hotlink with it.

```
sed -i 's/'"$1"' {height: 200px; ...
```

In the part where the function is called, you can call it as if it is another command, and you will supply the #hotlink argument to the command.

```
fnHotlinkG2R '#hotlink'
```

Comment: I think in addition, he'll need double quotes in order to get `$1` expanded inside his search/replace pattern, right?

Comment: @eckes: Actually it will expand without quote (I tested before posting the version without quote, not that thoroughly, though). However, it may not expand correctly if the input has spaces. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4899/var-vs-var-and-to-quote-or-not-to-quote

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Colour change functions

fnHotlinkG2R()
{
    $hotlinkOld = "$1";
    $hotlinkNew = "$2";
    sed -i "s/$hotlinkOld/$hotlinkNew/i" /var/www/html/style.css
}

And call it like this:

fnHotlinkG2R "#hotlink {height: 200px;width: 200px;background: green;"\
   "#hotlink {height: 200px;width: 200px;background: red;"
```

Comment: you are missing '#' in front of the '!' for a valid hash bang.

Answer (score 0):

First, your [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is wrong. The proper one is

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Secondly, in bash you use a "different" kind of parameter passing.

```
$0 expands to the name of the shell or shell-script
$1 is the first argument
$2 is the second argument and so on
$@ are all arguments
```

Read more in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Positional-Parameters)

You might be interested in the [quoting-part](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting) in the bash-manual as well...